# Unknown Twitter API issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

Right, so.

I'm trying to grab a list of friends from a given screen_name using the 'Twitter' module (found on npm, installed using `npm install twitter`), however, my program keeps failing, and I'm not sure why, exactly. At this point in time, all it's supposed to do is rattle off the list of the friends, contained within the friends JSON object, but that doesn't work, for some reason.

I can't tell why. The code is contained below. Please leave a comment if you need to ask a question.

```
function readTokenFromDisc(){ //Used to save on requests.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    fs.readFile('bearerToken.txt', 'utf8', function(error, data){
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

function buildClient(bToken){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var client = new Twitter({
      consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
      consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
      bearer_token: bToken
    });
    resolve(client);
  });
}

function grabTwitterFollowers(client){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.get('friends/list', {screen_name: 'POTUS'}, function (error, tweets, response){
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
      };
      resolve(tweets);
      console.log(tweets) //debug
      console.log(response) //debug
    });
  });
};

function initTwitter(){
  console.log('Test!') //debug, triggers
  readTokenFromDisc().then(function(contents){
    console.log('Othertest!') //debug, triggers.
    buildClient(contents);
  }).then(function(client){
    grabTwitterFollowers(client);
  }).then(function(following){
    console.log(following) //debug, output is 'Undefined'.
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing returns.

`grabTwitterFollowers(client);` and `buildClient(contents);`

in `initTwitter` should probably be

`return grabTwitterFollowers(client);` and `return buildClient(contents);`

Since that returns a promise for the chain. Otherwise, the promise will pass along `undefined`, the result of a function without a return.

Comment: That's it. I knew I was being an idiot somehow. Thanks for the help!